# MongoDB: Slow query exists in log file, but when I examine with explain it's fast

Tags: mongodb

I regularly check my MongoDB log file to find slow queries and solve it. Today I've seen a query that took 124ms and it's pretty high!

```
2018-09-29T18:19:57.016+0330 I COMMAND  [conn17674] command DataCrm.Ticket command: find { find: "Ticket", filter: { Jobs: { $elemMatch: { User: ObjectId('577370ae55477005ec9b657c') } } }, sort: { TicketNumber: -1 }, skip: 0, limit: 100, lsid: { id: UUID("dcf13400-816e-4b50-8591-654ac4d1daab") }, $db: "DataCrm" } planSummary: IXSCAN { Jobs.User: 1 } keysExamined:6496 docsExamined:6496 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:53 nreturned:100 reslen:246821 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 108 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 54 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 54 } } } protocol:op_query 124ms
```

As you can see I have an index on 'Jobs.User'. So I tested this query in shell:

```
db.getCollection("Ticket").find({ Jobs: { $elemMatch: { User: ObjectId('577370ae55477005ec9b657c') } } }).sort({ TicketNumber: -1 }).skip(0).limit(100).explain("executionStats");
```

The result is like below:

```
{ 
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
    "namespace" : "DataCrm.Ticket", 
    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "Jobs" : {
            "$elemMatch" : {
                "User" : {
                    "$eq" : ObjectId("577370ae55477005ec9b657c")
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "LIMIT", 
        "limitAmount" : 100.0, 
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "filter" : {
                "Jobs" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "User" : {
                            "$eq" : ObjectId("577370ae55477005ec9b657c")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "TicketNumber" : 1.0
                }, 
                "indexName" : "TicketNumber_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "TicketNumber" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "isUnique" : true, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                "direction" : "backward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "TicketNumber" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "rejectedPlans" : [
        {
            "stage" : "SORT", 
            "sortPattern" : {
                "TicketNumber" : -1.0
            }, 
            "limitAmount" : 100.0, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH", 
                    "filter" : {
                        "Jobs" : {
                            "$elemMatch" : {
                                "User" : {
                                    "$eq" : ObjectId("577370ae55477005ec9b657c")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "Jobs.User" : 1.0
                        }, 
                        "indexName" : "Jobs.User_1", 
                        "isMultiKey" : true, 
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "Jobs.User" : [
                                "Jobs"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "isUnique" : false, 
                        "isSparse" : false, 
                        "isPartial" : false, 
                        "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                        "direction" : "forward", 
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "Jobs.User" : [
                                "[ObjectId('577370ae55477005ec9b657c'), ObjectId('577370ae55477005ec9b657c')]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, 
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true, 
    "nReturned" : 100.0, 
    "executionTimeMillis" : 13.0, 
    "totalKeysExamined" : 640.0, 
    "totalDocsExamined" : 640.0, 
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "LIMIT", 
        "nReturned" : 100.0, 
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
        "works" : 641.0, 
        "advanced" : 100.0, 
        "needTime" : 540.0, 
        "needYield" : 0.0, 
        "saveState" : 10.0, 
        "restoreState" : 10.0, 
        "isEOF" : 1.0, 
        "invalidates" : 0.0, 
        "limitAmount" : 100.0, 
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "filter" : {
                "Jobs" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "User" : {
                            "$eq" : ObjectId("577370ae55477005ec9b657c")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "nReturned" : 100.0, 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
            "works" : 640.0, 
            "advanced" : 100.0, 
            "needTime" : 540.0, 
            "needYield" : 0.0, 
            "saveState" : 10.0, 
            "restoreState" : 10.0, 
            "isEOF" : 0.0, 
            "invalidates" : 0.0, 
            "docsExamined" : 640.0, 
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "nReturned" : 640.0, 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
                "works" : 640.0, 
                "advanced" : 640.0, 
                "needTime" : 0.0, 
                "needYield" : 0.0, 
                "saveState" : 10.0, 
                "restoreState" : 10.0, 
                "isEOF" : 0.0, 
                "invalidates" : 0.0, 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "TicketNumber" : 1.0
                }, 
                "indexName" : "TicketNumber_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "TicketNumber" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "isUnique" : true, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                "direction" : "backward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "TicketNumber" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }, 
                "keysExamined" : 640.0, 
                "seeks" : 1.0, 
                "dupsTested" : 0.0, 
                "dupsDropped" : 0.0, 
                "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
            }
        }
    }
}, 
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "VM1", 
    "port" : 27017.0, 
    "version" : "3.6.2", 
    "gitVersion" : "489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420"
}, 
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

As you can see the execution time is just 13ms that is a reasonable time. I don't understand what happens on logged query that consumed 124ms! Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the winning plan is `LIMIT -> IXSCAN`. It means that mongodb engine decided to use the `index(TicketNumber: 1)` to sort and continue to check matching until the limit number has been reached.
My mistake was that I had an ascending index on field TicketNumber and query tried to sort descending.
Now  I've added `index(TicketNumber: -1)` and now the execution duration reduced to only 26ms!